# What is the significance of cats in "Belle de Jour"?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, belle-de-jour

Severine asks her husband not to let the cats out while she's being whipped in the film's opening scene. Then, midway through the film, a butler bangs on the door of a room in a mansion and asks the owner if he should let the cats in. And later, in the final scene, we hear an audible cat's meow (as well as the horse-and-carriage noises) out the window.

It's a movie that's been around for a while, and I've read through several analyses of it on the web, but I haven't found a convincing explanation of the cat references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've seen *Belle de Jour,* but hopefully my memory can do it justice. The cat stuff seems to come from a combination of factors:

**First,** as Roger Ebert suggests in [his review of the film](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/great-movie-belle-de-jour-1967), Severine has lots of little, mundane fetishes that trigger her grandiose, kinky fantasies. As Ebert says:

> Severine is a masochist who likes to be handled roughly, but she also
>   has various little turn-ons that the movie wisely never explains,
>   because they are hers alone. The mewling of cats, for example, and the
>   sound of a certain kind of carriage bell. These sounds accompany the
>   film's famous fantasy scenes, including the opening in which she rides
>   with Pierre out to the country, where he orders two carriage drivers
>   to assault her.

These mundane sounds and images provide a transition into/out of Severine's fantasies. If I recall correctly, these visual and audio cues are actually used at the end of the film as a method to call into question how much of it is real and how much is part of Severine's fantasy world, though don't quote me on that bit.

**Second,** cats are often thought of as a [symbol of feminine sexiness and sexuality](http://meloukhia.net/2009/09/felinity_and_femininity/). Director Luis Bunuel could have easily decided that one of Severine's little turn-ons would be dogs, and give the mansion owner a bunch of little shih tzus or corgis instead of cats. But the cats seem to emphasize that this movie - Severine's fantasies, her involvement with the brothel, etc. - is about Severine's sexuality and autonomy, nobody else's. (Indeed, as Ebert suggests in his review, Severine's kinks seem to be very much about *her*, rather than any potential partner - even her husband.)

**And third,** as mentioned before, the director is Luis Bunuel, who is probably most famous for his collaboration with Salvador Dali that produced [*Un Chien Andalou*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0020530/?ref_=nv_sr_1) (fair warning to anybody who isn't already familiar: there are some rather violent/graphic scenes in the video).

(Fun fact: As you can kinda tell from the preview image that the imdb page shows on the trailer, the razor-to-the-eye shot was actually filmed using a dead cow - or possibly donkey? - rather than an actual person.)

But *anyway,* the point is that "presenting the audience with weird mysteries (often packaged in mundane things like cats or domestic squabbles) and never fully explaining them" is a Luis Bunuel trademark. I often find his work to be somewhat akin to existentialist theater like Eugene Ionesco's [*Cantatrice Chauve* (or *Bald Soprano*)](https://macaulay.cuny.edu/eportfolios/smaldone2011/files/2011/08/Bald-Soprano-script.pdf), in which a random, otherwise mundane phrase like "It's not that way, it's over here" makes up an important part of the story. Despite not being a particularly out-of-the-ordinary phrase in and of itself, it becomes (intentionally) strange and confusing by the sheer lack of explanation that surrounds it. (This seemingly innocuous phrase in *Bald Soprano* feels that much more odd because it comes directly after the characters spit out a bunch of phrases that are much more obvious nonsense - much in the same way that the cats and the meowing in *Belle de Jour* stand out as much as they do because they are so innocuous/mundane when placed next to Severine's fantasies about being whipped and having mud slung at her.)

Comment: Yes, I've read that Bunel liked to throw in random elements in his films.  But in this case, cat references appear (at least) in the first scene, the last scene, and a scene in the middle (as if planned).  Also, for the theory that the cats represent a personal kink of Severine's, it's odd that a cat reference is in the necrophiliac scene, where she appears to be contracted in her guise of "Belle de jour" -- in other words, it doesn't seem like a fantasy sequence, but one that has to do with her 2-5pm side job.  The other 2 cat scenes may be fantasy sequences, it's not clear that this one is.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the necrophilia scene is deliberately ambiguous as to whether it is a fantasy or not. The man who propositions her arrives in a horse drawn carriage which suggests it's a fantasy but she behaves as she does in the other, ostensibly real prostitution scenes, matter-of-factly removing her dress etc. This suggests to me that she is fantasising, but, perhaps feeling liberated by her carnal diurnal activities, she is able to take a more active, professional, though still masochistic role in this particular fantasy. But nonetheless I think Buñuel is trying to exploit the ambiguity between her fantasy life and her 'professional' life there, and it does effectively suggest another episode in her ongoing semi-delirium of sexual ecstasy/horror.